# Video embed flashing

Tags: video, streaming, embedded-resource

Can anyone help me with this video embed and tell me why it's flashing instead of playing the video?

http://www.seilingsfloors.com/dvd/

Update: I have verified that the .flv file is the correct size and am still experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video squeeze.flv is file corrupt. As it is only 25kB long chances are it has been severely truncated on upload.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing something like this:

```
 <param name="src" value="video_to_play.swf" />
```

or that you're missing the embed tag which could be something like this:

```
 <embed name="csSWF" src="video_to_play.swf" width="640"
                height="499" bgcolor="FFFFFF" quality="best"
                allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="csConfigFile=file=squeeze.flv"
                pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?
                P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed>
```

Good luck!